# better way to calculate mean of each row in polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I wrote this:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names": [1., 2., 3., None, 5],
    }
)

mean = df.mean(axis=1).to_frame('mean')
```

Can I use `select()` and `alias()` to achieve better performance and readability?

Comment: What does your original dataframe look like?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't think there's much performance gains to be had but we can avoid the pandas like syntax with the following:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list(pl.all()) # This will convert all your columns into a list per row
    .list.mean() # This takes the mean of the list
    .alias("row_mean")) # This names the result
```

You can replace the `pl.all()` with a list of columns in the event you don't actually want the average of all columns but just a few. You can replace it with `pl.exclude(columns_not_in_average)` to get the average of all columns except the ones you specify. Of course you can change the `with_columns` to `select` if you only want the new average column.

Answer (score 0):

I altered your test data to get a better sample size of 1,000,000:

```
{"nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5] * 200000,
"names": [1., 2., 3., None, 5] * 200000}
```

And tested two options:

[1] Just a standard mean, returning a series (`.to_frame()` and `.alias()` made practically no difference to execution time):

```
df.mean(axis=1).to_frame('mean')
```

[2] Using `with_columns()` to preserve the original data, whilst adding a new 'mean' column:

```
df.with_columns(mean = df.mean(axis=1))
```

Performance testing with `timeit` showed practically identical results, even having `with_columns()` being faster once, but I think it's just random variance based on CPU load / temp / throttling.

`with_columns()` has a much nicer output, and given the same performance, I'd go with that one. Sample output:

```
┌──────┬───────┬──────┐
│ nrs  ┆ names ┆ mean │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0  │
│ 2    ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 3.0   ┆ 3.0  │
│ null ┆ null  ┆ null │
│ …    ┆ …     ┆ …    │
│ 2    ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 3.0   ┆ 3.0  │
│ null ┆ null  ┆ null │
│ 5    ┆ 5.0   ┆ 5.0  │
└──────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better version of your code that maintain readability and a clear flow of operations.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, None, 5.0],
    }
)

mean = df.select(pl.all())
         .mean(axis=1)
         .alias('mean')

print(mean)
```

- Using `select(pl.all())` ensures that all columns are included in the calculation, making the code more flexible if you have additional columns in your DataFrame.
- `alias('mean')` is used to give the resulting column the name 'mean'

Comment: This seems an awful lot like a ChatGPT generated response. Not withstanding that, it doesn't really do anything relative to OP's question except add `select(pl.all())` which is a do nothing addition.